# Audin and Damian's notion of $C^1$ proximity

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, normed-spaces, vector-fields, morse-theory

I am reading Audin and Damian's book on Morse Theory and Floer Homology. In pages 40-41 they state the Smale Theorem, whose statement uses a notion of $C^1$-proximity for vector fields.

[image]

I believe the definition of proximity herein described has an issue.

I think the order of the quantifiers should be: "for every $\epsilon > 0$, *there exists a vector field $X'$such that* for every cover of V by charts..."

The way it is written, I could conceive of vector fields $X$ and $X'$ such that in an open chart $\varphi(\mathbb{B}^n)\subset V$ the first is
$$T\varphi^{-1}(X)(p) = a_1(p)\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}\vert_p+\cdots+a_n(p)\frac{\partial}{\partial x_n}\vert_p$$
and the second is
$$T\varphi^{-1}(X')(p) = b_1(p)\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}\vert_p+\cdots+b_n(p)\frac{\partial}{\partial x_n}\vert_p.$$

And they satisfy $$\lVert T\varphi^{-1}(X')(p) - T\varphi^{-1}(X)(p)\rVert<\epsilon$$ on compacts subsets of the unit ball.

Then if we set now $\tilde{\varphi}:2\mathbb{B}^n\to \varphi(\mathbb{B}^n)\subset V$, that is, we parametrize $\varphi(\mathbb{B}^n)$ by the ball of radius 2, and $\tilde{\varphi}^{-1}_i(p) = 2\varphi^{-1}_i(p)$, we end up with

$$T\tilde{\varphi}^{-1}(X)(p) = 2a_1(p)\frac{\partial}{\partial \tilde{x}_1}\vert_p+\cdots+2a_n(p)\frac{\partial}{\partial \tilde{x}_n}\vert_p$$
and the second is
$$T\tilde{\varphi}^{-1}(X')(p) = 2b_1(p)\frac{\partial}{\partial \tilde{x}_1}\vert_p+\cdots+2b_n(p)\frac{\partial}{\partial \tilde{x}_n}\vert_p,$$

so that
$$\lVert T\tilde{\varphi}^{-1}(X')(p) - T\tilde{\varphi}^{-1}(X)(p)\rVert<\epsilon$$
may be false on certain compacts, since for the same $p$ it is double the original $\lVert T\varphi^{-1}(X')(p) - T\varphi^{-1}(X)(p)\rVert<\epsilon$ (we may take the compact $K$ first to be say the closed ball of radius $\frac{1}{2}$, and then the closed ball of radius $1$ for the computation of the norm). This would mean that by changing the compact or open cover chosen we break the $\epsilon$ bound. That is, this notion of $C^1$ proximity doesn't seem to depend solely on the $X$ and $X'$.

Would someone be able to clarify what this notion of closeness is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The authors do not seem to state that $V$ is compact but I assume that is intended.

I think the order of quantifiers is not correct as stated (but you can read it in a way so that it makes sense), but yours is not what they are asking for either. I will explain the *conceptual content* of their statement, from which we can recover the intended order of quantifiers.

Audin and Damien are introducing a norm on the space $\mathfrak X(V)$ of vector fields on $V$: they want to say "There is a vector field $X'$ satisfying the desired properties, which is close to $X$ with respect to this norm."

The construction that Audin and Damien have in mind is the following. Given a chart $\varphi: \Bbb R^n \to V$, one may pull back the vector field to $\Bbb R^n$. Given a compact set $K \subset \Bbb R^n$, we may then measure the $C^1$-norm of $X$ *with respect to $\varphi$ and $K$* as $$\|X\|_{C^1, \varphi, K} = \sup_{p \in K} \left(\|d\varphi^{-1}(X_{\varphi(p)})\| + \|\nabla d\varphi^{-1}(X_{\varphi(p)})\|\right),$$ where we take the gradient by thinking of $d\varphi^{-1}(X)$ as a map $\Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R^n$.

Now given a finite collection $\mathcal C$, whose elements are $(\varphi_i, K_i)_{1 \leq i \leq n}$ pairs of charts $\varphi_i$ and compact sets $K_i \subset \Bbb R^n$, so that $\bigcup_i \varphi_i(\text{int}(K_i)) = V$, we may set $$\|X\|_{C^1, \mathcal C} = \max_{i=1}^n \|X\|_{C^1, \varphi_i, K_i}.$$

This is a norm on the space of vector fields. (It is a complete norm on the space of $C^1$ vector fields.) This norm depends on the choice of $\mathcal C$, but different choices give rise to \emph{equivalent} norms: if $N_1$ and $N_2$ are two norms arising from this process there is some $C > 0$ so that $N_1(X)/C \leq N_2(X) \leq C N_1(X)$.

---

Audin and Damien's claim is supposed to be: *fix ahead of time a collection $\mathcal C$ as above.* Then for any $\epsilon > 0$, there is a Morse-Smale pseudogradient field $X'$ with $\|X' - X\|_{C^1, \mathcal C} < \epsilon$.

This inequality will change wildly as we change $\mathcal C$, so we need to make such a choice ahead of time.

Thus the correct way to state their claim is: "For every cover of $V$ by compact subsets of charts, there is a vector field $X'$ so that (stated inequality) holds."

That is: you don't choose $X'$ after you choose a cover by charts and a *specific* compact subset of each chart so that $X'$ is small on that single compact subset. Rather, you choose a cover of charts, a compact subset of each chart, and then you want $X'$ to be small on *all of those chosen compact subsets*.

Different compact subsets will lead to a different notion of smallness. You will not be able to choose $X'$ so that it is $\epsilon$-close to $X$ with respect to all of these different notions of smallness.

Comment: This was very helpful! I haven't figured out the details, but to show that any two such norms are equivalent we have to rely heavily on these collections being finite, so that each transition function between charts in $C_1$ and $C_2$ has a constant that dominates any $\dfrac{\lVert d\varphi_2^{-1}(X_{\varphi(p)}) + \nabla d\varphi_2^{-1}(X_{\varphi(p)})  \rVert}{\lVert d\varphi_1^{-1}(X_{\varphi(p)}) +\nabla d\varphi_1^{-1}(X_{\varphi(p)})  \rVert}$, right? Then we can use the maximum of these constants for the inequality you wrote.